# What conditions on an Abelian category allow members of a direct sum to be determined entirely by their components?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

EDIT: In comments, with thanks to Maxime Ramzi, this question has a good answer in that what I want to be true is true when $\mathscr{A}$ satisfies axiom $\mathsf{AB}5$, that $\mathscr{A}$ is cocomplete and filtered colimits are exact. I suppose a new question is: is the truth of my question for $\mathscr{A}$ *equivalent* to exactness of filtered colimits in $\mathscr{A}$?

---

$\newcommand{\A}{\mathscr{A}}\newcommand{\tot}{\operatorname{Tot}^{\oplus}}$Weibel claims that if $\A$ is an Abelian category then, for a bounded below complex (of homological type) $C$ and any Cartan-Eilenberg resolution $Q$ of $C$, the map $\tot Q\to C$ is a quasiisomorphism. This is not too hard to show by a chase. However, as a side remark he mentions that we need $\A$ to be cocomplete to form $\tot Q$ in general - which I of course agree with - but the exact phrasing suggested he also believes $\tot Q\to C$ is a quasiisomorphism in that case. I don't believe this is true, and it was a bit ambiguous for me in the text.

Specifically, the obstruction is this: (letting $C$ be an unbounded complex) diagram chasing needs to be handled with care in Abelian categories. There is the formalism of what Mac Lane calls generalised members and we can use these to do a lot but it is important to remember these are not really elements of sets. The difficulty in the unbounded case is, in showing homological injectivity and demonstrating if a cycle of $\tot Q$ is a boundary in $C$ it must be a boundary in $\tot Q$ (forcing us to actually construct the boundary member):

> Suppose two members $x,y\in_m\bigoplus_{i\in J}X_i$ have the "same" components, meaning $\pi_jx\equiv\pi_j y$ for all $j\in J$. Must it follow that $x\equiv y$?

I believe this boils down to the following subquestion:

> Under what conditions on $\A$ is it true that if $a,b:Y\to\bigoplus_{i\in J}X_i$ are two arrows with $\pi_ja=\pi_jb$ for all $j$ we have $a=b$?

More technically it would suffice to show this is true for a certain class of $Y$, so long as this class represents all members up to equivalence and is closed under direct sum or something like that. Essentially, I'm asking:

> For which Abelian categories is $\bigoplus$ formed by some kind of "finite sum" construction?

I say that because the finite sum construction makes my question hold for categories of modules.

Comment: You're right that this is not true in general. It is true at least when filtered colimits in $A$ are exact, and I suspect the converse might hold, but I don't have a proof

Comment: W.r.t the last question: Every colimit is a filtered colimit of finite colimits. In particular, direct sums are filtered colimits of finite direct sums.

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Ok, so following Daniel's point I realise $\bigoplus_i X_i$ is the filtered colimit of the finite sums=finite products $\prod_{i\in F}X_i$ where $F\subset J$ is finite; I know my claim about members holds for products simply by the universal property of products; if I wlog consider the case $\pi_j a=0\forall j$ I might want to factor $a$ through the objects of this filtered colimit and use exactness to say something about the cokernel of $a$ being some colimit of cokernels for the finite products but ! $a$ need not factor through, unless $Y$ is compact. Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: Cokernels always commute with filtered colimits, the point of exactness here is to guarantee that filtered colimits of monomorphisms are monomorphisms. But for each finite subset $F$, the map from the finite direct sum to the infinite product is a (split) monomorphism !

Comment: @MaximeRamzi I think it's enough to require canonical transformation $\coprod \to \prod$ to be mono, but the "proof" I have in mind uses injective cogenerator, which obviously implies exactness of coproducts.

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Aha! So under your axiom on $\mathscr{A}$, I can assemble these monos to get a monomorphism $\bigoplus_i X_i\to\prod_i X_i$ and then use the obviousness of the claim for $\prod_iX_i$ to conclude. Very nice, thanks.

Comment: @DenisT of course, this being a mono is just a reformulation of the claim. I was giving an example of a common situation where this happens, namely exact filtered colimits. It might be equivalent but I'm not sure. FShrike : yes, exactly ! :)

Comment: Also I'd like to note/warn that there are several erroneous claims in Weibel's "Homological algebra", mostly ones related to generalisations of statements from module categories to arbitrary abelian ones; for example, it's claimed that the category of torsion abelian groups is not complete (it actually is, but forgetful functor to all abelian groups does not commute with products).

Comment: @DenisT Yes, I’m aware! I try to be very vigilant when I read any book and I’ve noted several errors or nontrivialities in generalising results for non-module categories

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *B. Mitchell. Theory of categories* (1965) three properties of abelian categories were introduced.

An abelian category is termed $C_1$ if it is cocomplete with exact coproducts, $C_2$ if it is bicomplete and natural transformation $\eta_{-, X}: \coprod_X (-_x) \to \prod_X (-_x)$ is mono for every set $X$, and $C_3$ if it is cocomplete with exact filtered colimits.

In bicomplete abelian categories the property in the OP is equivalent to $C_2$.

It's obvious that complete $C_3$ category is $C_2$, and $C_2$ always implies $C_1$ (it's in the 3rd chapter of Mitchell's book).

In the paper *Exactness of direct limits for abelian categories with an injective cogenerator* by L. Positselski and J. Stovicek [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.05156) one of the results is the following.

*Theorem*. Let $\mathrm A$ be a complete abelian category with an injective cogenerator $W$. (It is automatically cocomplete by special adjoint functor theorem.) Following conditions are equivalent:

- filtered colimits in $\mathrm A$ are exact;
- $\eta_{W, X}: \coprod_X W \to \prod_X W$ is mono;
- every morphism $f: W^{(X)} \to W$ factors through $\eta_{W, X}$;
- summation morphism $\sigma_{W, X}: W^{(X)} \to W$ factors through $\eta_{W, X}$.

As far as I know, there's no known example without injective cogenerator, $\eta$ being mono and non-exact filtered colimits. If there are no products (and, necessarily, no injective cogenerator), I suspect that this "local finiteness" condition on coproducts behaves quite patologically; it seems very unlikely to imply exactness of filtered colimits. Construction of a cocomplete but not complete abelian category is already quite involved; I haven't checked (yet) whether
[this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.10682) construction by J. Rickard serves as a counterexample to the updated question.

Comment: Regarding your last remark, the category that I constructed is AB5, so won’t be a counterexample.